# r looping through folders and searching for file and then concatenate data

Tags: r, csv, find, concatenation

I have a base folder and it has many folders in it. I want to go to each folder, find a file that has name table_amzn.csv (if exists) and then read all of those files in R and put all files in a single dataframe one after other. I have verified that all files have same columns. I know how to read CSVs into R. But how could i loop over all the folders within a base folder and concatenate data

Comment: get a list of file names with the specified pattern using `list.files()`; apply the list with `read.csv` to read in all the data frame into a single list; rbind the data with `do.call("rbind", list)`

Comment: `list.files(pattern = "table_amzn.csv", recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)` should climb all folder and search for a specific filename. Result should be full paths to the files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This also can be straightforward in base R:

```
## change `dir` to whatever your 'base folder' actually is
dir <- '~/base_folder'
ff <- list.files(dir, pattern = "table_amzn.csv", recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)

out <- do.call(rbind, lapply(ff, read.csv))
```

In the event that your columns are the same but for whatever reason (typo, etc) have different column names, you could modify the above like:

```
out <- do.call(rbind, lapply(ff, read.csv, header = FALSE, skip = 1))
names(out) <- c('stub1', 'stub2') # whatever they should be
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an implementation that was recently added to the package `rio`:

```
files <- list.files(pattern = "table_amzn.csv", recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)

devtools::install_github("leeper/rio")
library(rio)
df <- import_list(files, rbind = TRUE)
```

This will load all the objects in `files` to a single `data.frame` object. Alternatively, if you call with `rbind = FALSE` then a list of data.frames is returned